# set multiple parameters in criteria

Tags: criteria, smartgwt

I need to set multiple parameter in a criteria.
Can anybody please tell, how to achieve this in smartgwt

Actually my listgrid data need to filter with two id

```
int empID = 12;
int yearSpentID = 4;

Criteria c = new Criteria();
c.addCriteria("emp.id",empID);

listgrid.fetchData(c)
```

In this case listgrid data will be fetched filtered with employee id but i need to use employee id and also year spent id for filereing data on listgrid

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe missing something but this appears to be extremely simple: just call addCriteria() again:

```
c.addCriteria("yearSpendID", 4);
```